# How to de-normalize mysql database for user notifications?

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, denormalization, denormalized

I think it is necessary to de-normaize database for user notifications. For example, when flagging a post (which should be considered by user), we add a column of `flag ENUM('yes', 'no')` (or status column). Finding flagged events for a user can be by counting with WHERE clause of `user_id='XX' AND flag='yes'`.

This normalized structure is fine; but what if we have different types of notifications; e.g. flags for posts, comments, photos ... This means that we need to count several tables when the user is just visiting his profile page. This is more serious for a cross-project like stackexchange, as we get notifications for different sites.

I think de-normalization can help to add notification columns to the user table as

```
post_flags tinyint(3),
comment_flags tinyint(3),
photo_flags tinyint(3),
```

In this case, we need to run an additional write query for updating user flag columns on every corresponding actions. For example, when flagging a post: `UPDATE users SET post_flags=post_flags+1 WHERE user_id='XX'`. My concern is to ensure execution of the latter query to avoid any mismatch between this number and the count of flagged posts; but I think it can be secured by `TRANSACTION`.

In this way, we get all notification with one query for frequently visited profile pages.

Am I on the right track? or another tricky approach is common for this purpose?

Comment: what are you going to store in `tinyint(3)` ? aren't there multiple entries?

Comment: the number of notifications. For example, when flagging a post we will run query of `UPDATE users SET post_flags=post_flags+1 WHERE user_id='XX'`

Comment: "flag ENUM('yes', 'no')" - why not INT using 1 and 0?

Comment: what is wrong with ENUM? They both do the same with the same storage size.

Comment: Enum isn't SQL. Different platforms support it in different and incompatible ways. None of the mainstream commercial dbms support it at all, AFAIK. MySQL and PostgreSQL support it in different and incompatible ways. Changes to enumeration require altering the schema; changes to a table related by a foreign key reference requires only inserting a row. [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be better off with a table of user notifications.

```
create table user_notifications (
  user_id integer primary key, -- ? references users, not shown
  post_flags unsigned tinyint(3) not null default 0,
  comment_flags unsigned tinyint(3) not null default 0,
  photo_flags unsigned tinyint(3) not null default 0
);
```

A separate, narrower table is both logical and (probably) faster. Unsigned for flags, because negative numbers there make no sense, and MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints.

As far as normalization goes, user_notifications is in 5NF.

Comment: good design, but I am not sure if it is really necessary to split users and user_notifications into two columns, as the notifications can be added to the users columns. Since they are `tinyint`, they will be small in the table structure (even having lots of notifications).

Comment: Anything *can* be added to the table "users". That's not the question. The question you ought to ask is whether these flags contain information about the user, or about something else. The obvious answer is that they contain information about something else. (Information about notifications.) So logically they belong in a different table.  That narrower table will let more rows fit on a page, so you'll need to read fewer pages from disk--maybe a *lot* fewer pages. That means "faster".  (In my sandbox, about 1000 times faster to select one row with an empty cache--0.05ms vs 34.5ms.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this de normalising at all? It looks like creating those three columns is a better way to organise and seems more normal to me?

Comment: A good example here is accout balance. To look up transaction history of somebodies spending is heavy, so keeping track of the 'balance' means you only have one place to look. I think your on track!

Comment: I think it is de-normalization, as we are storing excess data!

Comment: Hmm good point. I think your design is good. Summary data is useful agains user accounts because of the amount of lookups needed. Another example is the profiles visits we keep track of. I count these but also store them in a subtable. In their profile page it's far quicker just fetching the one int value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is very effective. Maybe it's useful when you need to find also combinations of flags, for example post_flags OR comment_flags OR photo_flags and the order of the query is also important.

Comment: in the profile page, we need to show the number of all flags for a user. This mean, we need count query for each tables (posts, comments, flags).